# IPTables/Docker setup routing packets to INPUT chain instead of FORWARD

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I am running several installations with docker and iptables in place. One purpose of these installations is the forwarding of syslog messages. From time to time I experience outages in that network packets stop arriving at the container. In my current case, syslogs are being sent over port 514 to the host which is supposed to forward them to the container. Depending on the log source the packets arrive via UDP or TCP. Currently in one installation UDP packets do not arrive at the container.

This is the setup:

**(1) Container exposing ports 514 for TCP+UDP:**

```
/usr/bin/docker run --rm --detach \
-p 514:514/udp \
-p 514:514/tcp \
syslog-container \
${@}
```

**(2) Confirm with netstat:**

```
root@cc-01-m:~# netstat -plantu | grep 514

tcp  0 0 192.168.8.134:55228 10.68.8.70:514 ESTABLISHED 6844/rsyslogd
tcp6 0 0            :::514             :::* LISTEN      71629/docker-proxy
udp6 0 0            :::514             :::*             71644/docker-proxy
```

**(3) IPTables FORWARD (filter) and DOCKER (prerouting) chains:**

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target           prot opt in out     source      destination
285M 444G  DOCKER-ISOLATION all  --  *  *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0
203M 225G  DOCKER           all  --  *  docker0 0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 8087 packets, 4046K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1138M 904G  DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
pkts bytes target prot opt in      out source    destination
   0     0 RETURN all  --  docker0 *   0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
   1    52 DNAT   tcp  -- !docker0 *   0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0   tcp dpt:514 to:172.17.0.2:514
   0     0 DNAT   udp  -- !docker0 *   0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0   udp dpt:514 to:172.17.0.2:514
```

My view on this:

- Idential setup for both TCP and UDP
- PREROUTING/DNAT is not matching for 514/UDP
- there is an update below: I meanwhile added port 1514/UDP which is also working...

**(4) Result in dmesg:**

But in dmesg I see:

Working example (TCP, OUT=docker0)

```
[1220244.781877] [FW-ACCEPT] IN=ens192 OUT=docker0 MAC=00:50:56:9c:a0:21:00:09:0f:09:00:21:08:00 SRC=172.16.104.81 DST=172.17.0.2 LEN=2475 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=125 ID=10684 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57211 DPT=514 WINDOW=8212 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

Not working example (UDP, OUT=, meaning INPUT instead of FORWARD):

```
[1219701.100893] [FW-ACCEPT] IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:9c:a0:21:00:09:0f:09:00:21:08:00 SRC=172.16.102.19 DST=192.168.8.134 LEN=793 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=13050 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35541 DPT=514 LEN=773
```

172.17.0.2 is the docker container IP, 192.168.8.134 is the host IP. So, despite a matching PREROUTING there is no routing/forwarding done but it is matched *somehow* to INPUT.

**(5) DOCKER filter chain confirms that**

```
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
pkts  bytes target prot opt in out source destination
1562K 2347M ACCEPT tcp -- !docker0 docker0 0.0.0.0/0 172.17.0.2 tcp dpt:514
   0     0  ACCEPT udp -- !docker0 docker0 0.0.0.0/0 172.17.0.2 udp dpt:514
```

No counters for UDP here, PREROUTING failed.

**(6) Conclusion**

I can only conclude that this is a defect.

**(7) Question**

Can anyone make sense out of this? Are there steps to further troublehsoot or mitigate?

Thank you very much,
Andreas

**(8) Update**

I added a similar setup for port 1514/UDP (which was needed anyways). This just works. I am clueless. Could it be a load issue? There is a lot of traffic on port 514/UDP. Maybe the traffic starts before the docker interface is present and defaults to input since the PREROUTING is not (yet) possible??? Anybody?

When I try to determine the differences using the TRACE target, it looks like this:

(A) Working example (shortened for readability, port 1514):

```
[ 4760.393530] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=ens192 OUT= 
SRC=172.16.102.9 DST=192.168.8.134 ID=31601 PROTO=UDP SPT=63830 DPT=1514 LEN=472

[ 4760.393541] TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:1 IN=ens192 OUT=docker0 SRC=172.16.102.9 DST=172.17.0.2 ID=31601 PROTO=UDP SPT=63830 DPT=1514 
LEN=472

[ 4760.393546] TRACE: filter:DOCKER-ISOLATION:return:1 IN=ens192 OUT=docker0 SRC=172.16.102.9 DST=172.17.0.2 ID=31601 PROTO=UDP SPT=63830 DPT=1514 
LEN=472

[ 4760.393551] TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:2 IN=ens192 OUT=docker0 SRC=172.16.102.9 DST=172.17.0.2 ID=31601 PROTO=UDP SPT=63830 DPT=1514 
LEN=472

[ 4760.393556] TRACE: filter:DOCKER:rule:1 IN=ens192 OUT=docker0 SRC=172.16.102.9 DST=172.17.0.2 ID=31601 PROTO=UDP SPT=63830 DPT=1514 
LEN=472
```

(B) Not working example (shortened for readability, port 514):

```
[ 5122.397806] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=ens192 OUT= SRC=172.16.102.19 DST=192.168.8.134 ID=55657 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35541 DPT=514 LEN=451

[ 5122.397811] TRACE: filter:INPUT:rule:7 IN=ens192 OUT= 
SRC=172.16.102.19 DST=192.168.8.134 ID=55657 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35541 DPT=514 LEN=451

[ 5122.397822] TRACE: filter:OK:return:2 IN=ens192 OUT= 
SRC=172.16.102.19 DST=192.168.8.134 ID=55657 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35541 DPT=514 LEN=451
```

Remark: I have indeed a chain "OK" which logs and accepts.

Comment: Hi Andreas, please share the entire iptables rules output by executing these two commands #sudo iptables -n -L --line-number and #sudo iptables -L -n -t nat --line-number

Comment: Firewall rules work from top to bottom. First match wins the race.